# New command window quickly appears & disappears when typing 'gcc' command/gcc compiler not working properly

Tags: gcc, command-line, windows-7, mingw

I'm learning C and just installed MinGW which contains the GCC compiler. After installing and setting the path, anytime I type the 'gcc' command:

```
C:\Users\user>gcc palat.c -o palat.exe
```

or even just

```
C:\Users\user>gcc
```

another command window appears and quickly disappears. I'm using Windows 7. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: do you have to type the .exe at the end of the executable name? I know for g++, you just do: g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile

Answer (score 0):

USE `getchar();` so your box will appear and you see your result properly.

in return 0; box will gone immediately but in getchar(); is stuck there , if u want to see code with return 0; u need to run exe in cmd , so getchar(); is best for us if u use gcc or any compiler.

Comment: Can you clarify *why* he should use `getchar()`? Why will this show is result properly?

Comment: I use getchar(); , in return 0; box will gone immediately but in getchar();  is stuck there ,  if u want to see code with return 0; u need to run exe in cmd , so...... .i m learner now so i don't much know about c/c++ .

Comment: You should [edit] your answer, and include this information.

Comment: Ok Thanks For guiding.